# Cauchy principal value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I would like to show that $P.V \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x} dx=0$ I do not know why this cant be shown by means of a large semicircle, I proved that $P.V \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} dx=i\pi f(0)$ but it does not work with my case now since $e^{-x^2}$ is not analytic in the upper half plane, am I right?

Comment: The problem isn't that $e^{-z^2}$ isn't analytic (it is), it is that $e^{-z^2}$ isn't small in the upper (or lower) half-plane. But what about just directly computing $$\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\,dx + \int_\varepsilon^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\,dx\right)\;?$$

Comment: Your function is odd...

Comment: May you can help me with the integration, I do not see how to get an explicit expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is odd, so the integral is $0$.  Formally:

$$
I=\text{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\,\text dx = 
\lim_{\delta \to  0} \int_{-\infty}^{-\delta} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\,\text dx+
\int_{\delta}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\,\text dx
$$

In the first integral, let $x\mapsto -x$, so it becomes

$$\int_{\infty}^{\delta} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\,\text dx=-\int_{\delta}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\,\text dx\,.$$

Then,

$$I=\lim_{\delta \to  0} \int_{\delta}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\,\text dx-\int_{\delta}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\,\text dx = 0$$